# Generate password_hash which matches Magento Go API

Tags: magento, md5, salt

I am trying to authenticate a user through the Magento Go SOAP API and having problems generating a matching hash. According to the docs the password_hash contains password:salt however when I md5 it's not matching the password_hash.

Example:

1) I changed my password through admin control panel to 'testtest'

2) Run the following code:

```
$client     = new SoapClient('http://XXXX.gostorego.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session    = $client->login($api_user, $api_pass);

$params     = array('filter'=>array(array('key'=>'email','value'=>'user@domain.com')));

$data       = $client->customerCustomerList($session, $params);     

echo '<pre>CUSTOMER: '.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';

if (count($data)) {
    $hash   = explode(':',$data[0]->password_hash);
    $salt   = $hash[1];
    echo '<pre>HASH PARTS:'.print_r($hash, true).'</pre>';
    echo '<br>' .md5($salt.$password);
}
```

3) password_hash is  f35604820826428dd7633b91cd6078f4075c9bfa1a37db7bc70f563475ad8495:qK

4) MD5 is 0b04a656c770ba2f10b5918f94529cd8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done this with with Magento Go (and I'm not sure it's supported/possible) but the hash string

```
 f35604820826428dd7633b91cd6078f4075c9bfa1a37db7bc70f563475ad8495:qK
```

is too long to be a MD5 hash of a string. That's a 64 byte hash (plus the `:`, plus the salt `qK`).  My guess is it's SHA256, but that's a guess based on character length.

Comment: Life saver! Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 0):

On the backend, Both Md5 and SHA are being supported, with newer support leaning towards the SHA (in enterprise).

If your password were: 12341234

The DB Hash would infact be similar to: cdb757ce51af9749d2fabea4cf71dc72a1ec7b8721e5f8de83020f574ca3c5f1:TR

- And is indeed SHA256.

However, the remote connection should be "https:" over SSL for the WSDL file and you should be entering your SOAP API key in normal/plain text. 
ie:

- $username = "myUsername"; //ie. yourApiUsername
- $password = "myUserPass"; //ie. 12341234

If you want to replicate their hashing for your own internal purposes, you need to look at their methods: class Mage_Core_Model_Encryption

```
 public function hash($data)
{
    return md5($data);
}

/**
 * Validate hash against hashing method (with or without salt)
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $hash
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function validateHash($password, $hash)
{
    $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
    switch (count($hashArr)) {
        case 1:
            return $this->hash($password) === $hash;
        case 2:
            return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
    }
    Mage::throwException('Invalid hash.');
}
```

Enterprise:

```
public function hash($data, $version = self::HASH_VERSION_LATEST)
    {
        if (self::HASH_VERSION_MD5 === $version) {
            return md5($data);
        }
        return hash('sha256', $data);
    }



    /**
     * Validate hash by specified version
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $hash
     * @param int $version
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateHashByVersion($password, $hash, $version = self::HASH_VERSION_LATEST)
    {
        // look for salt
        $hashArr = explode(':', $hash, 2);
        if (1 === count($hashArr)) {
            return $this->hash($password, $version) === $hash;
        }
        list($hash, $salt) = $hashArr;
        return $this->hash($salt . $password, $version) === $hash;
    }
```